# Can't manage to fetch img url from a typescript file

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I am making a simple app in ionic that as one of the features will have an option to show a list of registered users, with their profile pictures. Their profile pictures are stored inside firebase storage.

I successfully retrieve the URLs to the profile images, but when I try linking them to my `<img>` in my HTML file, it doesn't seem to work.
The URL I get is valid, when I try copy pasting it to the `<img>` tag it works, but I  want it to be dynamic.

registeredusers.html file:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let profile of profiles">
  <ion-avatar item-left> <ion-img [src]="profile.url"> </ion-img> </ion-avatar>
  <h2>{{profile.name}}</h2>
  <span>{{profile.country}}</span>
  <button ion-button (click)="followProfile(profile.name);" outline item-right>Follow</button>
</ion-item>
```

registeredusers.ts file:

```
export class RegisteredusersPage {

    private profileListRef = this.db.list<Profile>('profile-list');
    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController, 
        public navParams: NavParams, 
        private storage: Storage,
        private db: AngularFireDatabase, 
        private toastCtrl: ToastController, 
        public angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth
    ) {}

    profiles = [];
    firestore = firebase.storage();
    
    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad RegisteredusersPage');
        this.getProfile();
    }

    getProfile() {
        console.log(this.db.list('profile-list'));
        var database = firebase.database();
        var ref = database.ref("profile-list");
        ref.on('value', this.gotData.bind(this), this.errData.bind(this));
    }

    async gotData(data) {
        console.log(data.val());
        var profilesArr = data.val();
        var keys = Object.keys(profilesArr);
        var that = this;
        var array = [];
        console.log("profilesArr: " + profilesArr);
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            var k = keys[i];
            var profileName = profilesArr[k].name;
            var profileCountry = profilesArr[k].country;
            var profileEmail = profilesArr[k].email;
            let imageName = k + "__" + "profile";
            if (profileName && profileCountry && profileEmail && profilesArr[k].email != this.angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.email) {
                const profileImageUrl = await this.firestore.ref().child(profileEmail + "/images/" + imageName).getDownloadURL();
                array[i] = profilesArr[k];
                profilesArr[k].url = profileImageUrl;
                if (profilesArr[k].email != this.angularFireAuth.auth.currentUser.email) {
                    this.profiles[i] = profilesArr[k];
                    console.log("profiles[i].url:" + this.profiles[i].url);
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(this.profiles);
    }
```

The `{{profile.name}}` and `{{profile.country}}` inside are alright, and the `this.profiles[i].url` returns the correct URL, but I can't seem to reference it from the HTML file.

Not sure if it matters, but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raUzn.png) is how my page looks like.

Comment: check if is necesary use "http://...", else the app look for the img in assets folder

Comment: Edited: oh nevermind, I understand you, I'll try now. But the profiles[i].url is in this format https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/***************c0

Comment: where are your pictures? if they are in a folder you can use [src]="'folder/'"+profile.url, but if is in a server you must indicate angular the http: [src]=" ' h t t p :/ / www.dominio.com' "+profile.url

Comment: why dont you just make a property of `imageUrl` and assign it to src so that you can assign an iamge dynamically if it was coming from backend? Also try to make use of `[src] ="../../profile.png"

Comment: I put the src attribute like this: [src]="'http://'"+profile.url     but it threw an exception: ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '+profile.url' is not a valid attribute name.  Not sure if I put it right? My profile.url variable already contains the "https://" part.

Comment: I would make it, but the problem is that I have more than only 1 image, so it has to be an array. @ahsan

Comment: `console.log("profiles[i].url:" + this.profiles[i].url);` are you getting any output at this line? are you unable to bind your pictures to the frontend?

Comment: Yes, it gives me this link https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ionicappstream.appspot.com/o/a%40a.com%2Fimages%2F2jpJ6uOzDoXk4xGS5j4uHMmoAPT2__profile?alt=media&amp;token=7c02c417-6232-4909-a7aa-1da76b767b79. If I Just put the link in the img tag as so <img src="LINK">  it works, but that's just one picture, I want to list it for each profile, dynamically. Stackoverflow shortens the URL i put here in this comment, but there is "https://" from the left side of the link and the path from the right side of the url.

Comment: try showing the data in table listing form.

Comment: I am very sorry if I am being annoying, but I am very new to web dev, and I don't understand what you meant by that, sorry!

Comment: try the answer that i provided

Comment: I saw it, and it actually worked, went back now to approve answer and now your answer is gone :(

Comment: it is there now and you should tag the person who you are addressing because we won't get notifications otherwise :)

Comment: Yes it is, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div class="body table-responsive">
    <table class="table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%; padding: 10px;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
         <th style="width:10%">Image</th>
        </tr>
      <thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let profile of profiles">
        <td>
         <img [src]="profile.url" class="img-circle">
        </td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Based on this answer, all I did was change the ion img tag to the regular img tag and now everything is working well.

Comment: glad to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

You might to include DOMSanitizer Class.

```
constructor(
        public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
```

In Template:

```
<ion-img [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(profile.url)"> </ion-img>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But unfortunately, it gives me this error: ERROR TypeError: newSrc.indexOf is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer that *ahsan* provided, all I did was change  tag to the regular  and now everything is working well.

So instead of

```
<ion-avatar item-left> <ion-img [src]="profile.url"> </ion-img> </ion-avatar>
```

I made it like this

```
<ion-avatar item-left> <img [src]="profile.url"> </ion-avatar>
```

Thanks to everyone that contributed to solving my problem!